# How can you make the angle made by the intersection of two HTML elements be rendered as a curved slope?

Tags: html, css, angular-material, frontend

I'm using Angular Material v16, and I have a mini-FAB that floats at the edge of a mat-sidenav which may open based on any number of interactions; when the button gets clicked, the tab collapses (closes).

This sidenav is not actually used to show navigation elements, but to dynamically embed content (that part I've sorted out), and currently has the floating button at the edge as I mentioned.

However, I want for it to have the intersection of the button's right side and the edge of the sidebar (i.e., the resulting 90° corners of their intersection) to blend making curved slopes (simply for aesthetic purposes), as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPTmi.png).

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this. Using svgs would be fine, but I would like to keep the template code quick and simple and just make use of some CSS tricks if it's suitable.

This is my template currently:

```
<mat-sidenav-container [hasBackdrop]="false">
  <mat-sidenav mode="over" opened="true">
    <button mat-mini-fab style="position: absolute; top: 50vh; left: -1.5rem;">
       <mat-icon>arrow-forward-ios</mat-icon>
    </button mat-mini-fab>
    <ng-template appDynamicSidebarContent></ng-template>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <!-- Main content -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```